# Why does Microsoft Edge reorder html attributes before rendering a page?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

So I wrote some Javascript that scrolls to a place on the document when the user clicks on a button:

```
document.getElementById("navContact").addEventListener("click", scrollToSection);

function scrollToSection() {
    /* this = element on which the user clicked */
    smoothScroll(this.attributes[0].value.split("#")[1]);
}
```

It's nice, simple, easy to read and debug. The only issue is that it gets the name of the section to which it must scroll by reading it from a named node map. In my markup, the attributes are ordered like so:

```
<a href="#contact_us" id="navContact"></a> 
<--! document.getElementById("navContact").attributes = [href="contact_us", id="navContact"] -->
```

But when I check this in Edge's DOM explorer, the attributes are reordered:

```
<a id="navContact" href="#contact_us"></a>
<--! document.getElementById("navContact").attributes = [id="navContact", href="contact_us"] -->
```

As per Josiah Keller's suggestion I'm changing the js to use `element.getAttribute()` instead of `this.attributes`.

In the meantime, I'm dying to know, why does Edge do this?

Comment: ...why not just read the attribute using `getAttribute()`?

Comment: As for why it doesn't preserve the order, I'm guessing they're just stored in some sort of data structure optimized for fast access.  The order isn't supposed to matter.

Comment: Thank you. There are so many methods that I forgot I could just do that.

Answer (score 4):

`.attributes` returns a NamedNodeMap.  [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap):

> The NamedNodeMap interface represents a collection of Attr objects.
>   Objects inside a NamedNodeMap are not in any particular order, unlike
>   NodeList, although they may be accessed by an index as in an array.

While you can reference it with `this.attributes[0]`, you'll notice that you can't `push` to it because it's not an array.  It's an object, it's constructed without order in mind, and so it's probably not a bug in Edge.  It's still returning what it's supposed to, which is an unordered object.

As others are suggesting, you should just get the href specifically, but hopefully this sheds some light on *why* it's not working as you might think.

Comment: The *attributes* property returns a **NamedNodeMap**, not a list. There is also an "order" inferred by the [*HTML specification*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#namednodemap): "*Let names be the qualified names of the attributes in this NamedNodeMap object’s attribute list, with duplicates omitted, in order.*". So an order is inferred, and likely the order should be the same as the [*attributeList*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element-attribute) it's based on.

Comment: I don't think the reordering is a side-effect of placing the attributes into a named node map. This behavior doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox. And the elements always appear in the same order - just not _my_ order.

Comment: @RobG: (The DOM spec, not the HTML spec.) Huh, interesting. Previous DOM specs ([1](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1780488922), [2](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922) and [3](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922)) all stated explicitly that order is in no way guaranteed with NamedNodeMap, but that text is now gone from the living spec. (Or it was never in WHATWG's vision of the DOM to begin with...?)

Comment: @BoltClock—yeah, sorry, should have scrolled to the top. ;-) If they say "*in order*" there should be something that says what the order is. Since ECMAScript objects don't have any order (even Array properties aren't in any order, there's no guarantee that *for..in* will return a property named "0" first, certain versions of IE didn't) they might still be working out how to define it.

Comment: Typo fixed.  Thanks, @RobG.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use el.getAttribute('href') instead?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute